# jsoup nullpointerexception

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse the below HTML using JSoup:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <span class="today" title="Today's weather summary for Moody">Today</span>
     <div>
        High 
        <strong class="high">27</strong> 
        <span class="split">|</span> 
        Low 
        <strong class="low">21</strong> 
       °C
    </div>

    ...
```

I'm trying to get the values 27 and 21. However when I try using the method below I get java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
Element temperature = doc.select("div.row collapse > strong").first();
```

When I use the method below the values are replace by '--'. The output is: *Today High -- | Low -- °C --% Chance of Precip.*

```
Element temperature = doc.select("span.today");
```

Why are the values replaced?
Are they populated by a script and '--' are just HTML placeholders?

If so is there are another way of obtaining these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well assuming that's your complete html you can simply go for the specifics

```
String high = doc.select("strong.high").text() ;
String low  = doc.select("strong.low").text() ;
```

if you need to be more specific you can try using the outer `div`

```
String high = doc.select("div[class=small-6 columns]").select("strong.high").text() ;
String low  = doc.select("div[class=small-6 columns]").select("strong.low").text() ;
```

Comment: Both methods return an empty string for me. The complete HTML I'm trying to parse is https://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=33.593%2C-86.49&MR=1

Comment: @Ricardo it looks like the javascript update mate, you have two options here: 1- use a java script downloader like selenium 2- go through the code and see where and to what function the call occur.

Comment: @Ricardo something like this :
https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/33.587719/-86.477615/forecast/daily/5day.json?language=en-US&units=e&apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e

Comment: Ended up using openweathermap api, thanks for the help.